# How to get back-end url from apim app insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I have an apim instance configured to log to application insights.

I run the following kusto query to pull back useful info:

```
requests
| extend requestBody = customDimensions["Request-Body"]
| extend requestMethod = customDimensions["HTTP Method"]
| extend ApiName = customDimensions["API Name"]
| where ApiName == "client"
| project  timestamp, ApiName, url, requestBody, requestMethod
| sort by timestamp desc
```

The "url" that this returns is the inbound url of the apim instance. Does anyone know how this can be updated to also pull back the back-end url that apim forwarded the request onto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing the logs of the backend application to the same instance of Application Insights you can simply join your query result with the "requests" table using the operation_Id of the APIM request and the operation_ParentId of the backend request.

You can also join the APIM requests with the dependency table. This should also give you the backend requests:

```
dependencies
| where timestamp > ago(1h) 
| join (requests | where timestamp > ago(1h))
  on operation_Id
```

After that you can extract the fields you are interested in.

**EDIT**:
To get the backend URL field only with data logged by APIM and without the backend logging to Application Insights you can use the 'data' field of the dependency table joining requests and dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies
| where timestamp > ago(1h) 
| join (requests | where timestamp > ago(1h))
  on operation_Id
  | project backendUrl = data
```

Comment: The backend application is a 3rd party api. I simply want to present the url of this api that my api management instanced called. Good to know that it’s possible to join to dependencies as you’ve show (I didn’t know that) but that’s fare more sophisticated than the info I’m looking for.

Comment: APIM does its own dependency tracking, so you can simply add "| project data" to above sample code to get the backend url.

Comment: project data gives "Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'data'". What I'm after is the name of the property that will show the backend url that was called